# Need help to understand how to access the returned results of an INDEXEDDB request result array

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm new to INDEXEDDB and i've got a getAll method working on my object store, but i cannot figure out how to access the results of what i've returned.

This is my code that is being called from a 'click' event listener on my form:

```
var request = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);
      request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
        // Create a new object store if this is the first time we're using
        // this DB_NAME/DB_VERSION combo.
        //request.result.createObjectStore(STORE_NAME, {autoIncrement: true});
      };
      request.onsuccess = function() {
        db = request.result;
        console.log('Database opened!');
        
        var transaction = db.transaction(STORE_NAME, 'readonly');
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(STORE_NAME);

        if ('getAll' in objectStore) {
          // IDBObjectStore.getAll() will return the full set of items in our store.
          objectStore.getAll().onsuccess = function(event) {
            console.log("getAll Success");

            // .gList is an unordered list on my PHP page that i am attempting
            // to populate with the returned values.
            let list = document.querySelector('.gList');
            list.innerHTML = `<li>Loading...</li>`;

            // This is successful and returns the data that i expect as displayed below.
            let request = event.target;

            // This shows the results of my request
            console.log({request});
            // this returns undefined.  I've tried all manner of ways of 
            // referencing the array that is inside this returned IDBRequest object
            // and that is what i cannot figure out.
            **console.log('request attr ' + request.team1Name);**
```

The top-level results of the returned IDBRequest object look like this:

```
{request: IDBRequest}
request: IDBRequest
error: null
onerror: null
onsuccess: ƒ (event)
readyState: "done"
result: Array(1)
0: Array(1)
0: {gameDate: "2021-08-29", gameTime: "12:38 PM", team1Name: "TeamOne", team2Name: "TeamTwo", gameCompleted: false, …}
gameID: 1
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
source: IDBObjectStore {name: "gamesList", keyPath: "gameID", indexNames: DOMStringList, transaction: IDBTransaction, autoIncrement: true}
transaction: IDBTransaction {objectStoreNames:
etc......
```

Clearly, i have the results that i seek, yet i cannot figure out how to navigate thru the IDBRequest object in order to get my data.  How do i (a) get my result array values and (b) do it properly?
cheers

Comment: And just to clarify, my goal isn't to simply get the values to display in the console, although i figure that once i got that working, the rest would be routine.  What i'm really after is a way to get the returned values from IDB into variables.  I've been exploring the map() function, but i haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAll` produces a result that is an array. For example:

```js
function query(db, myCallbackFunction) {
  const tx = db.transaction('mystore');
  const store = tx.objectStore('mystore');
  const request = store.getAll();

  request.onsuccess = event => {
    // denote the array of objects with a variable
    // here, event.target is === to request, can use either one
    const data = event.target.result;
    // pass the data to the callback function so that caller can
    // access it
    myCallbackFunction(data);
  };
}

// Open the database and then run the query
var openRequest = indexedDB.open('mydb');
openRequest.onsuccess = event => {
  query(db, (data = []) => {
    // This gets called when the query has run with the loaded
    // data
    console.log('received %d rows of data', data.length);
    for (const row of data) {
      console.log('object:', row);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: thank you, i am going to work this out tomorrow morning, but this is a pretty thorough explanation, which i appreciate very much!  I need to understand callback functions a little better, i think.

Comment: This worked well for me, i used async/await rather than callbacks, but your answer put me on the right track.  Thank you!